# open collector digital output

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, diodes, protection

I have a digital output board design which has 32 open collector (sinking) outputs which can be connected in parallel to drive a resistive load. The collector of each output transistor is connected to a cathode of IN4001 diode. The anode of this diode is connected to the FIELD connector (where it is connected to a resistive load and 24V supply.

What is the use of this diode?

[image]

Comment: Can you post a link to the board or possibly a schematic?

Comment: There has to be a positive common field connection too.

Comment: Are you sure the collectors are connected to the cathodes (the end with the line)?

Comment: Are these outputs sinking (n-p-n transistor) or sourcing (p-n-p transistor)? In the second case, as they connected (to the cathodes), these diodes can prevent the [flyback voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode).

Comment: @Circuitfantasist . the outputs are sinking type.

Comment: Then, since you said below, "the diode is connected between load and collector of npn transistor", the collectors should be connected to the anodes to prevent the flyback voltage.

Answer (score 1):

This series diode is most likely intended to protect against reverse polarity.  The external load is most likely powered by its' own power supply, where the negative lead of that external supply is connected to circuit ground on this board.  The positive lead of the supply feeds the high-side connection of the loads.

Those series diodes are intended to protect the loads and driver circuits against damage if that external power supply is connected backwards.  That is: (+) to circuit ground, (-) to the loads.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent flyback voltage, most probably. I'm not quite sure what you mean by "FIELD" connector though.

However, your question suggests the diode is connected in such a way that it connects between collector and emitter (if that's what FIELD means), in which case the diode could be there to stop Vc sinking below Ve and popping the transistor.

In all likelihood it has been added by the board's manufacturer to prevent accidental destruction of any transistor, as a form of increasing the longevity of the board.

Comment: The outputs are sinking and field means a resistive load through a 24V supply.The diode is connected between load and collector of npn transistor.

Comment: That implies that the diode is in series between the   collector and load, so you can't connect the load directly to the transistor. I can't quite see the point of this, the only effect I see it having is to reduce the voltage across the load by ~0.7V.